# Count distinct values for each column, return a dataframe, and sort values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code:

```
for column in list(data.columns):
    pd.DataFrame(columns=column, data=data.columns.nunique()).sort_values()
```

This doesn't work......

Either to define a function or use a for loop, how can I make it simple to check the unique value number of each column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many issues with your code, but the two main ones:

- You don't store, print, or append to a list the `pd.DataFrame` objects you create.
- You are applying `nunique` to column labels, not to the data within your dataframe.

Here you can use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) directly with your dataframe, then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5)))

res = df.nunique()\
        .sort_values(ascending=False)\
        .rename('Count')\
        .to_frame()

print(res)

   Count
1      5
3      4
2      4
0      4
4      3
```